# N-grams for letter in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I want to do n-grams method but letter by letter

Normal N-grams:

```
sentence : He want to watch football match

result:
he, he want, want, want to , to , to watch , watch , watch football , football, football match, match
```

I want to do this but letter by letter:

```
word : Angela 

result:
a, an, n , ng , g , ge, e ,el, l , la ,a
```

This is my code using `Sklearn` , but it is still word-by-word not letter-by-letter:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 100),token_pattern = r"(?u)\b\w+\b")

corpus = ['Angel','Angelica','John','Johnson']

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
analyze = vectorizer.build_analyzer()
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(vectorizer.transform(['Angela']).toarray())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an `'analyzer'` param which does what you want.

According to [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):-

> **analyzer** : string, {‘word’, ‘char’, ‘char_wb’} or callable
>
> Whether the feature should be made of word or character n-grams. Option ‘char_wb’ creates character n-grams only from text inside word boundaries;
>   n-grams at the edges of words are padded with space.
>
> If a callable is passed it is used to extract the sequence of features
>   out of the raw, unprocessed input.

By default, it is set to word, which you can change.

Just do:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 100),
                             token_pattern = r"(?u)\b\w+\b", 
                             analyzer='char')
```